# GWT + GAE Servlet URL and Servlet Mapping

Tags: java, apache, google-app-engine, gwt

http://127.0.0.1:8888/socialnetwork/contactsService

That's the current URL for one of my servlets. My question is, how do I change it?

In my web.xml file, altering

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>contactsServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/socialnetwork/contactsService</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>contactsServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/a/contactsService</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Makes absolutely NO difference to the URL it requests when I make an RPC-call to the servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have done the above you need to change where you invoke (Which is described in the Annotation below) as in...

```
// The RemoteServiceRelativePath annotation automatically calls setServiceEntryPoint()
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("email")
public interface MyEmailService extends RemoteService {
  void emptyMyInbox(String username, String password);
}
```

See http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteServiceRelativePath.html